# Eclipse not showing javadocs of a jar located in a referenced project

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I have a Dynamic Web Project (say ProjectA) in my Eclipse Mars workspace. One of the libraries is inside hibernate-core.jar. In this project, I set the Javadoc Location for this jar to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/.
Everything works fine. Eclipse shows Hibernate javadocs correctly.

I created a second pure Java project (ProjectB). In it's build path I reference ProjectA, so I can use it's classes. I also reference the "Web App Library" of ProjectA, so I can use not only ProjectA classes but also the libraries of ProjectA like Hibernate.

In ProjectB Eclipse doesn't show javadocs for any of the libraries of ProjectA. I tried to set Javadoc Location of hibernate-core.jar in ProjectB. It seems to work but javadoc still doesn't show. If I check the location again, it's blank. Eclipse won't save the location for a referenced library no matter how many times I try.

If I try to "Open Attached Javadoc in a Browser" I get the message:

> The documentation location for 'any hibernate class' has not been
>   configured. For elements from libraries specify the Javadoc location
>   URL on the properties page of the parent JAR ('path to jar in
>   ProjectA')

Crazy! This is exactly what I'm doing. The Javadoc Location in ProjectB remains blank and the Javadoc Location in ProjectA is correctly set and working there.

Any ideas on how to make Eclipse show javadocs for a referenced library?

Comment: i just tried your scenario, same result with yours, this may be a bug of eclipse

Comment: Reported a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497850) on this.